# How can I change slick-dots inline style "display: block;" to "display: flex;"?

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

```js
<ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;">
   <li class=""><button>1</button></li>
   <li class=""><button>2</button></li>
   <li class="slick-active"><button>3</button></li>
</ul>
```

I want to value block to flex
But I can't find the code from my vsc.
I think those codes are inherent automatically.
How can I correct it?

Comment: style={{display:"flex"}} in react you can add like this.

Comment: in react the use of the {class} is not supported but instead you use className = "slick-dots", so pls kindly note this, and can you explain better what you are trying to achieve , that way we could provide a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="slick-dots" style={{display: "flex"}}>
 <li class=""><button>1</button></li>
 <li class=""><button>2</button></li>
 <li class="slick-active"><button>3</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, simple and clean.

```
<ul className="slick-dots" style={{ display: "flex;" }}>
   <li className=""><button>1</button></li>
   <li className=""><button>2</button></li>
   <li className="slick-active"><button>3</button></li>
</ul>
```